# Como ejecutar una funcion antes de cargar el DOM en VUEX?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex, frontend

Quiero Ejecutar un funcion antes de cargar el DOM para traer los datos de una API, sé que en vue es con before Create pero como lo hago en la tienda VUEX?

Comment: debes de revisar el ciclo de vida de vuex para comprenderlo mejor https://vuex-orm.org/guide/digging-deeper/lifecycle-hooks.html#defining-lifecycle-hooks

Comment: No hay otra forma que no sea instando ese complemento adicional?

Comment: Y porque no ejecutas un action en el beforeCreate del componente App?  Estas corriendo una SPA?